# What's mean "enabled: ture force: true" properties in this code?

Tags: spring, encoding, yaml

```
  http: 
    encoding:   
      charset: UTF-8
      enabled: true
      force: true
```

What's mean "enabled: ture   force: true" properties in this code?

Comment: This looks like its a yaml config file for something. You need to give it some context!

Comment: Sorry, this is the context. I just want to create Board with using yml file.
spring:  mvc:
    static-path-pattern: /resources/**
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
      suffix: .jsp
  http: 
    encoding:   
      charset: UTF-8
      
      enabled: true
      force: true
  messages:
    basename: message
    encoding: UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

**spring.http.encoding** is depracted in the new spring boot versions (>2.3). So new application.setting should look like this:

```
server:
  servlet:
    encoding:
      enabled: true
      charset: UTF-8
      force: true
```

> **server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8** # Charset of HTTP requests and responses. Added to the "Content-Type" header if not set explicitly.

> **server.servlet.encoding.enabled=true** # Whether to enable http encoding support.

> **server.servlet.encoding.force=true** # Force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests and responses.

Reference: [Appendix Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html)

Comment: Thanks! Your reply is help a lot!